# issues running docker traefik v2.0 to use self signed certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, tls1.2, traefik

i am trying to run docker traefik v2.0 to use self signed certificates

here is my traefik.toml file

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "/certs/server.crt"
    keyFile = "/certs/server.key"
```

and here is my traefik.yaml docker-compose file
version: '3.5'

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik_network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./certs:/certs/
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"

networks:
  traefik_network:
     name: traefik_network
```

the certificates are in the folder `certs/server.crt` and `certs/server.key`

but when i run the docker-compose for traefik i get the following error

```
Attaching to traefik
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:11 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:14 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:17 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:19 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:22 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:24 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:29 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:36 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:08:50 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:09:16 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:10:08 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:11:09 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:11:14 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:11:17 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
traefik    | 2019/10/20 21:11:19 command traefik error: field not found, node: tls
```

anyone know what the issue is?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the [migration documentation from Traefik v1 to v2](https://docs.traefik.io/migration/v1-to-v2/#tls-configuration-is-now-dynamic-per-router), the configuration of TLS is not in the entrypoint anymore, but in a router's configuration instead :

You have to define a router (following the migration documentation if you still use v1's  frontends / backends) that will look like

```
[http.routers]
  [http.routers.Router-1]
    rule = "Host(`bar.com`)"
    service = "service-id"
    [http.routers.Router-1.tls]
      options = "myTLSOptions"

    # will terminate the TLS request
```

in which you can use `myTLSOptions` as a reference to a TLS option section defined like so:

```
[tls.options]
  [tls.options.myTLSOptions]
    minVersion = "VersionTLS13"
    cipherSuites = [
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        ...
        ]
    ...
```

The certificates' location is in a separate config entry:

```
[[tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "/certs/server.crt"
    keyFile = "/certs/server.key"
```

Notice that you can also use a different format for your config in v2: you can do more than before with docker labels and if you prefer, you could instead also change from toml to yaml.

Comment: i have a question as i am not very clear on this..if i use `traefik.toml` file with my docker run..will traefik still be able to do service discovery and attach new services dynamically? or i have to always update this file to include all other apps i run to be routed by traefik? that is one thing that has never been clear to me

Comment: I'm not certain about traefik v2, but the way it worked in v1 was that, in traefik.toml, you could define backends, frontends, and default options, and then in the labels of docker containers (or swarm services) you could override those options and/or declare new backends/frontends pairs (dynamically!). Now traefik v2 doesn't use the same mechanisms but I would assume that you can still use a config file (toml or yaml) together with docker labels with no problem. You might need to specify a list of providers as command line options (you've already done so for docker). I hope this helps.

Comment: yeah that helps...thanks for the explanation...now in the tls certs config section..you only listed option for server cert and key..what about the ca cert? i mean if this is self signed by self CA...then wont option for the ca cert be required to work?

Comment: you only listed option for server cert and key..what about the ca cert? i mean if this is self signed by self CA...then wont option for the ca cert be required to work?